# Determine the moments of inertia of the thin plate of mass m which has a shape of a circular sector shown in the figure about x,y and z axes

Tags: homework-and-exercises

[image]

I wonder if i can solve this question by using area moments of inertia? Or do i need another solution?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example **type** questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/75633) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/75633). You might want to consider posting on [some other Physics website](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/391/75633), such as the [PhysicsForums](https://www.physicsforums.com/forums/homework-and-coursework-questions.152/).

Answer (score 1):

I am confused by the question. They are asking for the product of inertia about the coordinate axes. What is definetly clear is that you have to calculate the mass moment of inertia, not the 2nd moment of area, so the formulae in the blue rectangle will not work. I suppose what they mean by product of inertia are the off-diagonal elements of the inertia tensor, i.e. $I_{xy}, $ $I_{xz}$ and $I_{yz}$. For the $I_{xy}$ we have $$I_{xy}=\rho\int_V-xy\,dV$$ with $x=r\,cos\theta$, $y=r\,sin\theta$, and thickness $t$ $$I_{xy}=-\rho\int_Vr^2cos\theta\,sin\theta\,dV = -\frac{\rho t}{2}\int_0^\beta\int_0^a r^2\,sin2\theta\,r\,dr\,d\theta=-\frac{\rho t}{2}[\frac{r^4}{4}]_0^a\int_0^\beta sin2\theta\,d\theta =\frac{\rho t a^4}{8}[cos2\theta]_0^\beta $$ $$I_{xy}=\frac{\rho t a^4}{8}(cos2\beta-1)=\frac{1}{8}Ma^2$$ where $M=\rho t a^2 (cos2\beta -1)$. The $I_{xz}$ and $I_{yz}$ can be computed in the same manner.

I hope I did not mess anything up. Hopefully, someone with a better understanding of this topic will post an answer as well.